# jest test case for URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jestjs

---

search looks like this search: "?productId=1234" and changeId is action

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

 const productId = urlParams.get('productId');

  if(productId){
  this.props.changeId(productId);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The difficult part is how to set the mock value to `window.location.search`.

E.g.
`index.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  console.log(window.location.search);
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  return urlParams.get('productId');
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('60959971', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const location = {
      ...window.location,
      search: '?productId=1234',
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      writable: true,
      value: location,
    });
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe('1234');
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60959971/index.test.ts (12.89s)
  60959971
    ✓ should pass (34ms)

  console.log stackoverflow/60959971/index.ts:129
    ?productId=1234

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.136s
```

Comment: This works, but how do you set things back to normal at the end? My mock is persisting in other tests!

Comment: @BenWheeler you can use a `afterEach()` in your `describe` which resets the window.location without the `search` property

Answer (score 2):

Updated with my solution in 2022 with react, react-router-dom and jest

My jest test is as follows

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

test('My component does change search params', () => {
 const getPageParams = () => {
       const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
       const index = parseInt(searchParams.get("index"));
       const query = searchParams.get("query");
       return [index, query];
}

render(
      <BrowserRouter>
          <MyComponentThatManipulatesSearchParams />
      </BrowserRouter>
);
const [actualIndex, actualQuery] = getPageParams();
expect(actualIndex).toBe(1);
expect(actualQuery).toBe("happyhacking");

// as a quick check, you can also log the URL
console.info(window.location.href);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Include jest.resetModules() and it works!