# How can I test that url search changed with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, jsdom

I have a component which reacts to url search changes, and a button that changes the url search. I want to test that when I click the button, the component reacts accordingly. Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-url-change-test-b5zq1.

App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const [urlChanged, setUrlChanged] = useState(false);
  const handleURLSearchChange = () => {
    window.location.search = new URLSearchParams({ foo: "bar" });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.search.length !== 0) {
      setUrlChanged(true);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-label="change" onClick={handleURLSearchChange}>
        Change URL search
      </button>
      <p aria-label="URL Status">{urlChanged ? "Changed!" : "Not yet"}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.spec.js

```js
describe("App", () => {
  it("Reacts to url changes when touching the button", async () => {
    render(<App />);
    const button = await screen.findByLabelText("change");
    userEvent.click(button);
    const label = await screen.findByLabelText("URL Status");
    await waitFor(() => expect(label).toHaveTextContent("Changed!"));
  });
});
```

The problem is I'm getting:

```
    Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)
```

Note: I'm only able to see this error if I donwload the sandbox, and run npm install and npm test.

Do I have to mock the window.location object with both setters and getters? What's the better way to do it?

Comment: JSDOM doesn't support navigation: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2112. You either need to replace `window.location` with a test double, or use something like React Router (see https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing for how to test).

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your component code implementation.

If the second argument is an empty array, `useEffect` will only execute once, so changing the value of `window.location.search` in the event handler `handleURLSearchChange` will not trigger `useEffect` again. You need to check `location.search` in the event handler to decide if set the value of `urlChanged`.

As @jonrsharpe's comment said, JSDOM doesn't support navigation. We need to mock it using `Object.defineProperty()`.

Besides, the instance of the `URLSearchParams` class can NOT be assigned to `window.location.search`. Use `.toString()` to convert it to string.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [urlChanged, setUrlChanged] = useState(false);
  const handleURLSearchChange = () => {
    window.location.search = '?' + new URLSearchParams({ foo: 'bar' }).toString();
    if (window.location.search.length !== 0) {
      setUrlChanged(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-label="change" onClick={handleURLSearchChange}>
        Change URL search
      </button>
      <p aria-label="URL Status">{urlChanged ? 'Changed!' : 'Not yet'}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('Reacts to url changes when touching the button', async () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: {
        search: '',
      },
    });
    render(<App />);
    const button = await screen.findByLabelText('change');
    let label = await screen.findByLabelText('URL Status');
    await waitFor(() => expect(label).toHaveTextContent('Not yet'));
    userEvent.click(button);
    label = await screen.findByLabelText('URL Status');
    await waitFor(() => expect(label).toHaveTextContent('Changed!'));
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67572637/App.test.tsx (8.34 s)
  App
    ✓ Reacts to url changes when touching the button (48 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.tsx  |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 | 8                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.906 s
```

Comment: This is no longer the case, jest dom has improved and supports this natively. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965057/2468129 for more

Comment: @Lxrd-AJ Good to know, thanks.